# Latitude and Long are null until second startup, Google Maps and Permissions

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, permissions

I am working on a simple map app that tracks the location of the device and returns location information.  Everything works on the second start up of the app.  It runs through onCreate, onMapReady, onConnected, then onRequestPermissionResult.  I need the permission result to pop up before onConnected..

```
    @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap gMap){
    //Gets map ready and checks permissions
    mGoogleMap = gMap;
    mUiSettings = mGoogleMap.getUiSettings();
    mUiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        String [] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, Perm_Read_Fine);
    }
}
```

and

```
    @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull
int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case Perm_Read_Fine: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //Perms Granted
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Nope", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you be more specific about second startup?

Comment: Its like opening the app a second time after it fails the first it has information in the lat and long and then works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google maps uses user's lastknownLocation for location,  If the location is unknown it takes time to fetch location. I would suggest to use LocationListener or updates.

```
       if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                        (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            }, 1);

        }
        else {

            // enable location buttons
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

            // fetch last location if any from provider - GPS.
            final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            final Location loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            //if last known location is not available
            if (loc == null) {

                final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {

                        // getting location of user
                        final double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        final double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        //do something with Lat and Lng
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                        //when user enables the GPS setting, this method is triggered.
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                        //when no provider is available.
                    }
                };

                //update location every 10sec in 500m radius.

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 500, locationListener);
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10000, 500, locationListener);
            }
            else {
                //do something with last known location.
                // getting location of user
                final double latitude = loc.getLatitude();
                final double longitude = loc.getLongitude();
            }
        }
```

Permission handling:

```
     @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {

        case 1:
            if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                //do something
            }
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out soon and get back to you!

Answer (score 0):

try this change :

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);
  }
}
```

You were using ContextCompat instead of ActivityCompat , and it has to "!=" instead  of "==" , since u need to check when permission are not granted

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.